# How to use Google Analytics to track visitors who come from a particular entry page

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is it possible to track, e.g pageviews, time on site etc., only those visitors who come from a particular entry page, eg.`http://www.abc.com/123?qwe=456` to my site using Google Analytics. If yes, then how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Google Analytics, select 'Behaviour' in the left hand menu.

Then navigate to 'Site Content' > 'Landing Pages'.

Select the landing page in question, and this will detail those metrics you specify for only visitors to your website via the selected landing page.

If you want these visitors broken down further still, just select a secondary dimension at the top of the table.

I would certainly suggest playing around there as it sounds like this would achieve what you're after.

Comment: thanks Geoff, is there any limit on number of landing Pages?

Comment: Google Analytics will track everything on your website, every visit, every click (providing you have the tracking code inserted on every page). GA's capacity for showing instances within a table (for any dimension / view) is 5000.

Comment: And of course you can build segments based on the landing page, so you can use almost all reports in GA limited to those users who came in through a certain url.